# Best way to burn data to dvd using command line

Tags: command-line, dvd, burning

I have three kinds of file:

```
Iso file, Directory, Txt file,

ISO: debian7.iso
Directory: Archives from /var/cache/apt/archives
File: README
```

I want to burn them into a DVD using command line...

**NOTE:**

I don't want my `iso file` be extracted

What I tried is:

```
sudo wodim  dev=/dev/dvdrw -v -data /path/to/debian7-64bits/
```

But is gives me errors

What is the best way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: "But is gives me errors"? what errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found:

```
sudo growisofs -Z /dev/sr0 -r -J /path/to/debian7-64bits/
```

(OR)

```
sudo wodim  dev=/dev/sr0 -v -data /path/to/debian7-64bits/
```